# Unordered echo in php

Tags: php, echo

I'm testing things in php, and I found a strange thing in the expected result.

This is the program I used:

```
<?php
$tags = $_GET['tags'];
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$langs = $_GET['langs'];
echo var_dump($tags).$uid.var_dump($langs);
?>
```

And the request:

```
myfile.php?tags[]=IT&tags[]=CS&uid=userIdent&langs[]=basque&langs[]=spanish
```

And the result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "IT" [1]=> string(2) "CS" } array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "basque" [1]=> string(7) "spanish" } userIdent
```

I don't understand why the uid isn't echoed between the two var_dump functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump()` doesn't return the string, it does its own output. The entire argument of `echo` is evaluated before `echo` prints anything. So your statement is equivalent to:

```
$temp1 = var_dump($tags);
$temp2 = $uid;
$temp3 = var_dump($langs);
echo $temp1.$temp2.$temp3;
```

Since `var_dump()` doesn't return anything, `$temp` and `$temp2` will be empty. So it's actually equivalent to;

```
var_dump($tags);
var_dump($langs);
echo $uid;
```

Answer (score 1):

echo isn't going to echo out `$uid`, instead it will try to output the result of `var_dump` which I think is `void`

You probably want:

```
var_dump($tags);
echo $uid;
var_dump($langs);
```

but `var_dump` is normally used for debug, not rendering the final result

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating **the return values** of `var_dump` with `$uid`. Since `var_dump` doesn't return anything, that's nothing. So `null . $uid . null` will get concatenated and `echo`d. But long before that is happening, the two `var_dump` calls have already dumped their *output* to the screen.